# Is it possible to install metasploit on Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compatibility, metasploit

I know that it is possible to install Metasploit on iPhones and somehow on Android mobile devices, today I installed ubuntu emulator and try ubuntu touch directly from my computer and I have a question: Is it possible to run Metasploit on Ubuntu touch?